# Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value (Function) to type Logical

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

I am trying to apply a user's manually input fields as a filter to data connection (called IKX).

Here is an example of the user input data:

| BUYER CODE FILTER |
| --- |
| 104 |
| 800 |

I have a table that applies the code format of the power query filter:

| BUYER CODE FILTER FORMAT | FORMULA |
| --- | --- |
| [BUYER_CODE] = 104 | IFERROR(IF(LEN(InputBuyerCodes[@[Buyer Code Filter]])>0, "[BUYER_CODE] = " &InputBuyerCodes[@[Buyer Code Filter]], ""),"") |
| or [BUYER_CODE] = 800 | IFERROR(IF(LEN(InputBuyerCodes[@[Buyer Code Filter]])>0, " or [BUYER_CODE] = " &InputBuyerCodes[@[Buyer Code Filter]], ""),"") |

Then a table that concats these fields:

| CONCAT BUYER CODE FILTER FORMAT | FORMULA |
| --- | --- |
| [BUYER_CODE] = 104 or [BUYER_CODE] = 800 | CONCAT(Table2[Buyer Code Filter Format]) |

In power query I have a connection to the "CONCAT BUYER CODE FILTER FORMAT" table that drills down the table to just [BUYER_CODE] = 104 or [BUYER_CODE] = 800 called ConcatBuyerCodeFilterFormat

To apply the filter to the IKX data, I added the below step: 
=Table.SelectRows(Source, each (ConcatBuyerCodeFilterFormat) )

and get the error 
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "[BUYER_CODE] = 104 o..." to type Logical.
Details:
Value=[BUYER_CODE] = 104 or [BUYER_CODE] = 800
Type=[Type]

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you.  It shows how to filter, with the filter definition in another variable

```
let Source =#table({"Column1"}, {{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}}),
crit="[Column1] = ""a""",
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, Expression.Evaluate("each "&crit))
in #"Filtered Rows"
```

All that said, if you start off with the first filter table, why not just merge that against your larger data table and remove the rows with no match?

Comment: You're right I made it way too complicated. I merged my large data table to the smaller Buyers Code Table  that I wanted to use as my filter with an inner join.  Achieved the results I wanted and will be less easy to break by the users!